# how to add colors for app bar in primarySwatch widget but color is be from (fromARGB and fromRGBO)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget

i need how to call const varibale for primarySwatch but i need add color is be (fromARGB and fromRGBO)
note:
AppBarColors are varibale

```
const AppBarColors = Color.fromARGB(1,100, 255, 100,);
    primarySwatch: AppBarColors,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Below code hope it's helpful to you change rgbo color your need

```
primarySwatch:Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 0.4)
```

Refer color class library from official documentation of flutter [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html)